# What do the values to android:backgroundDimAmount mean?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-theme

The documentation for android:backgroundDimAmount says:

"public static final int backgroundDimAmount

Default background dim amount when a menu, dialog, or something similar pops up.
Must be a floating point value, such as "1.2".

This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

Constant Value: 16842802 (0x01010032)"

What is this float, 1.2, actually mean? What number signifies having 100% fade out (what's the highest number float I can use?)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Values are between 0 and 1. Zero meaning there is no dimming, and 1 meaning 100% black.